# New TomEE server can't run Vaadin UI

Tags: tomcat, vaadin

I'm trying to run my Vaadin application on a new TomEE server, and I can't get it to work. I only get the following error message:

```
ALLVARLIG: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/serverside_imr]]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/serverside_imr]]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/vaadin/server/VaadinServlet
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.openejb.core.TempClassLoader.loadClass(TempClassLoader.java:205)
  at org.apache.openejb.core.TempClassLoader.loadClass(TempClassLoader.java:79)
  at org.apache.xbean.finder.archive.FileArchive.loadClass(FileArchive.java:88)
  at org.apache.xbean.finder.archive.CompositeArchive.loadClass(CompositeArchive.java:58)
  at org.apache.xbean.finder.archive.FilteredArchive.loadClass(FilteredArchive.java:45)
  at org.apache.xbean.finder.archive.CompositeArchive.loadClass(CompositeArchive.java:58)
  at org.apache.openejb.config.WebappAggregatedArchive.loadClass(WebappAggregatedArchive.java:80)
  at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder$ClassInfo.get(AnnotationFinder.java:1453)
  at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.findMetaAnnotatedClasses(AnnotationFinder.java:563)
  at org.apache.xbean.finder.AnnotationFinder.findMetaAnnotatedClasses(AnnotationFinder.java:512)
  at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$DiscoverAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:1250)
  at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer$DiscoverAnnotatedBeans.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:469)
  at org.apache.openejb.config.AnnotationDeployer.deploy(AnnotationDeployer.java:356)
  at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory$Chain.deploy(ConfigurationFactory.java:401)
  at org.apache.openejb.config.ConfigurationFactory.configureApplication(ConfigurationFactory.java:962)
  at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.startInternal(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1214)
  at org.apache.tomee.catalina.TomcatWebAppBuilder.configureStart(TomcatWebAppBuilder.java:1087)
  at org.apache.tomee.catalina.GlobalListenerSupport.lifecycleEvent(GlobalListenerSupport.java:130)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5378)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
  at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
... 39 more

mar 03, 2015 8:10:20 EM org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase startInternal
ALLVARLIG: A child container failed during start
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.report(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1123)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost]]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1575)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1565)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:816)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 6 more

mar 03, 2015 8:10:20 EM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
ALLVARLIG: The required Server component failed to start so Tomc  at is unable to start.
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardServer[8005]]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:689)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
  at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
  at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardService[Catalina]]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:739)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 7 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina]]
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:154)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:443)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: A child container failed during start
  at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:1131)
  at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:300)
  at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
... 11 more
```

I noticed that Eclipse can't find "com.vaadin.server.VaadinServlet", which is probably the main reason the UI can't be run. How do I solve this without having to make a new project from scratch?

Comment: what exactly have you changed?  where is your vaadin-server jar gone?

Comment: @cfrick It got accidentally deleted, so I had to try to insert the vaadin files back into the project. The project has the jar files, including vaadin-server, but it's possible I missed some.

Comment: why don't you get your deps managed (maven, gradle, ant, younameit)?  or automate your setup for the tomee?  the next time, something is fishy or someone else hast to take over, you will waste same amount time...

Answer (score 0):

First of all make sure that you have not mention the servlet mapping of VaadinServlet twice. that is in web.xml file (create by you) and WebServet annotation in default Java file created by the project default.

Remove servlet mapping from either web.xml file or default Java file (Annotation).

Hope this will fix the issue.